# Obtengo el error en Python: "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este codigo en Python versión 3.6

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pxssh

usuario = open("usuario.txt", "r")

for usuario in usuario.read().split("\n"):
    password = open("password.txt", "r")
    for password in password.read().split("\n"):
        try:
            conectar=pxssh.pxssh()
            conectar.login("localhost",  str(usuario), str(password))
            print "Usuario y Password correcto es:"
            print "[+] Usuario: {}". format (usuario)
            print "[+] Password: {}". format (password) 

    except :
    
        print "[-] Usuario y Password Incorrecto"
        print "[-] Usuario {}". format (usuario)
        print "[-] Password {}". format(password)
```

El problema es el error que me manda al intentar ejecutar el programa el cual es

> File "program.py", line 14
> print "Usuario y Password correcto es:"
> ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Ya busque en Internet y no pude encontrar una respuesta. Se agradece la ayuda.

Comment: no es lo mismo cuatro espacios que una tabulación

Answer (score 4):

El problema radica en que tu linea `except` esta fuera de la condición, recuerda que `try` y `except` deben ir al mismo nivel. Ya que es el mismo proceso por así decirlo.

```
import pxssh

usuario = open("usuario.txt", "r")

for usuario in usuario.read().split("\n"):
    password = open("password.txt", "r")
    for password in password.read().split("\n"):
        try:
            conectar=pxssh.pxssh()
            conectar.login("localhost",  str(usuario), str(password))
            print ("Usuario y Password correcto es:")
            print( "[+] Usuario: {}". format (usuario))
            print ("[+] Password: {}". format (password))

        except :

            print( "[-] Usuario y Password Incorrecto")
            print ("[-] Usuario {}". format (usuario))
            print ("[-] Password {}". format(password))
```

Comment: Al parecer ese no es el problema, sigue sin funcionar!

Comment: que error te muestra

Comment: Exactamente :   File "Sara.py", line 14
    print 'Usuario y Password correcto es:'
                                          ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @JuanVial Python te lo está diciendo: en algunas líneas has usado espacios para indentar, en otras has usado tabuladores, quizás en otras una mezcla de ambas cosas. Debe ser consistente y usar siempre el mismo mecanismo para indentar (recomiendo espacios). Python exige eso al menos dentro de cada bloque, pero es más sencillo si lo mantienes consistente en todo el fichero. Un buen editor debería ayudarte con ésto y usar siempre espacios aunque pulses tab, si estás editando código python.

Answer (score 0):

Es extraño pero si borras la sangria (o tabulacion) que esta justo en esa linea y luego la "escribes" denuevo con la tecla de tabular, te va a funcionar. Saludos.

Comment: Esto pasa por que los *cuatro espacios* no son lo mismo que *la tabulación*.